# MongoDB createIndexes() Method - Support for individual Index Options

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

Does MongoDB createIndexes() method, support specifying individual options for each index set in the script. Something like this below, which is not working by the way.

Ref - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndexes/#mongodb-method-db.collection.createIndexes

```
var indexes = [
  {
    key: { "productId":1, "productName":1 },
    partialFilterExpression: { "catalog": { $exists: true} },
    name:"productId_productName_catalog_partial"
  },
  {
    key: { "productId":1, "createdDate":1 },
    sparse: true,
    name:"productId_createdDate_only"
  }
  
];
db.product.createIndexes(indexes);
```

Error

```
{
    "message" : "Error in specification { key: { key: { productId: 1, productName: 1 }, partialFilterExpression: { catalog: { $exists: true } }, name: 'productId_productName_catalog_partial' }, name: 'key_[object Object]_partialFilterExpression_[object Object]_name_productId_productName_catalog_partial' } :: caused by :: Unknown index plugin 'productId_productName_catalog_partial'",
    "ok" : 0,
    "code" : 67,
    "codeName" : "CannotCreateIndex"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

While what you describe does seem to be a limitation of the helper/wrapper function, it does *not* seem to be a limitation of the underlying [createIndexes command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/) itself.

Here is an example that creates three indexes each with different options/properties:

```
> db.foo.getIndexes()
[ 
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' } 
]
rS [direct: primary] test> db.foo.runCommand({
  createIndexes: 'foo',
  indexes: [
    { key: { x: 1 }, name: 'x_1', unique: true },
    { key: { y: 1 }, name: 'y_1', sparse: true },
    {
      key: { z: 1 },
      name: 'z_1',
      partialFilterExpression: { z: { exists: true } }
    }
  ]
});
{
  numIndexesBefore: 1,
  numIndexesAfter: 4,
  ok: 1,
  ...
}
rS [direct: primary] test> db.foo.getIndexes()
[
  { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_' },
  { v: 2, key: { x: 1 }, name: 'x_1', unique: true },
  { v: 2, key: { y: 1 }, name: 'y_1', sparse: true },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { z: 1 },
    name: 'z_1',
    partialFilterExpression: { z: { exists: true } }
  }
]
```

Original answer regarding the helper/wrapper function below.

---

The [Options section](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.createIndexes/#options) of the documentation you linked has this to say on the matter:

> IMPORTANT
>
> When you specify options to `db.collection.createIndexes()`, the options apply to all of the specified indexes. For example, if you specify a collation option, all of the created indexes will include that collation.
>
> `db.collection.createIndexes()` will return an error if you attempt to create indexes with incompatible options or too many arguments. Refer to the option descriptions for more information.

That, and the outcome of your testing, suggests that the answer to your question is: No, specifying options for the indexes individually is not supported with this command.

Comment: Well, I hope MongoDB provides this feature in future, as this would also help in index maintenance and versioning in case of reindex situation.

Comment: Check the updated answer - looks like this _is_ possible using the underlying command itself.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please check it out, upon trying the way you have mentioned, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the below way of execution works fine with multiple index set with different option specification.

"name" field is a mandatory one which also makes it to work.

```
db.runCommand({
    createIndexes: "product",
    indexes: [
        {
            key: { "productId": 1, "productName": 1 },
            partialFilterExpression: { "catalog": { $exists: true } },
            name: "productId_productName_catalog_partial"
        },
        {
            key: { "productId": 1, "createdDate": 1 },
            sparse: true,
            name: "productId_createdDate_only"
        }
    ]

});
```

Output

```
{
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "ok" : 1
}
```